# VB6 Call stored procedure with parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, vb6

As the headling says I want to call a stored procedure with parameters. 
Below is the VB6-function that

Private Sub TestProcedur()
    Dim strSql         As String
    Dim CPw            As rdoQuery

```
strSql$ = "? = {call Insert_Student(?) }"
Set CPw = gRdoConn.CreateQuery("InsertStudent", strSql)

CPw.rdoParameters(0).Direction = rdParamReturnValue



CPw(1) = "FRANK"

Set mrsR = CPw.OpenResultset()
```

End Sub

The stored procedure below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_Student
    @Name VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Student (Name)
    VALUES (@Name)
END
GO
```

I'm getting a problem when running the function. A ERROR messsage occurs when running the line "CPw.rdoParameters(0).Direction = rdParamReturnValue" that says: Not valid description index"

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Is this better then? I got a problem when running the function a get a ERROR messsage that says: "Could not find item indicated by text"

Comment: Is there a reason your using RDO over ADO? If your just starting this project you should consider changing over.

Comment: Im working with leagacy code from an old project. Thats why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page on MSDN should explain it nicely:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240826%28v=VS.60%29.aspx

Comment: Im getting a problem when running the function. A ERROR messsage occurs when running the line "CPw.rdoParameters(0).Direction = rdParamReturnValue" that says: Not valid description index"

Comment: No Microsoft documentation explains things nicely.  Examples are either missing, incomplete, or overburdened.